# "Linguistic processing" in Unicode code point conversion?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, char

The MSDN documentation for [`Char.ConvertFromUtf32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> A valid code point outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) always yields a valid surrogate pair. **However, a valid code point within the BMP might not yield a valid result according to the Unicode standard because no linguistic processing is used in the conversion.** For that reason, use the System.Text::UTF32Encoding class to convert bulk UTF-32 data into bulk UTF-16 data.

What is the "linguistic processing" referred to above? Are there any cases where a `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i)[0]` call might give a different result from `(char)i` for characters in the BMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 65535; i++)
{
    char ch1 = (char)i;

    if (i < 0x0d800 || i > 0xdfff)
    {
        string str1 = char.ConvertFromUtf32(i);

        if (str1.Length != 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\\u+{0:x4}: char.ConvertFromUtf32(i).Length = {1}", i, str1.Length);
        }

        char ch2 = str1[0];

        if (ch1 != ch2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\\u+{0:x4}: (char)i = 0x{1:x4}, char.ConvertFromUtf32(i)[0] = 0x{2:x4}", i, (int)ch1, (int)ch2);
        }
    }

    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    string str2 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes);

    if (str2.Length != 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\\u+{0:x4}: Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes).Length = {1}", i, str2.Length);
    }

    char ch3 = str2[0];

    if (ch1 != ch3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\\u+{0:x4}: (char)i = 0x{1:x4}, Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes)[0] = 0x{2:x4}", i, (int)ch1, (int)ch3);
    }
}
```

The only difference seems to be in the 0xd800 - 0xdfff range, where the `char.ConvertFromUtf32()` will throw an exception, while the `Encoding.UTF32.GetString()` will return 0xfffd for the invalid character.

On the [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/text/utf32encoding.cs#L1011) we can clearly see that there is no "special processing" for UTF32 characters.

```
if (iChar >= 0x10000)
{
    *(chars++) = GetHighSurrogate(iChar);
    iChar = GetLowSurrogate(iChar);
}

// Add the rest of the surrogate or our normal character
*(chars++) = (char)iChar;
```

(I've omitted various lines of code that are irrelevant to this discussion)

Comment: Thanks for writing the code to check! The range [`U+D800`–`U+DFFF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF) is reserved for surrogate characters, which are invalid as code points outside UTF-16, so the exception / fallback character is to be expected. If this is the only difference, I assume the MSDN documentation is mistaken, and was presumably referring to some Unicode normalization that shouldn't be part of the code point conversion.

Comment: @Douglas I've even checked in the reference source of `UTF32Encoding` and there is no "special handling".

Comment: It's a pity that MSDN have removed the facility to add comments to their documentation. Mistakes such as this one should be pointed out.